# how to make image slider into while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a website retrieving images from database. The database has multiple records (ROWS). I am using while loop to retrieve the records. Every record having three or four images. I want to use a horizontal image slider into the while loop to retrieve all the records. I searched in the net. there are lot of slider. But nothing was in the loop. if I put them into the loop it was not working. please help me some one.

example slider: http://wowslider.com/automatic-jquery-slider-noir-squares-demo.html?affid=331J-S9

for example:

```
<?php
While($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          **I need horizontal slider here**;
          }
?>
```

Comment: seems you need to be more clear to get your answer.

Comment: tell me what I have to clear in my question.

Comment: do you require, 3 images together in one slide? and those 3 images relating to the same row?

Comment: yes every row has three images. so I want to put a slider for each row.

Comment: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified check this link. seems it matches your requirement of 3 images per slide..

Comment: sir, I thing still you did not understand my question. I need 10 slider per page if row is 10 per page. so every one slider must be in  each row. so, every one slider must be in deferent ID. so I don't know to make ID as variable. if I put a variable as id it is not working.

Comment: did you check my below answer!!!

Comment: yes, i saw your below answer. It was not my question that a slider has how many images. my question is i need 10 slider per page .every slider must be diferrent Id. so ID only my problem.

Comment: fine buddy.. sorry, didn't get it right.. what i understood, accordingly i have placed my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @yaseenahmed I updated my answer tell me if it's what you were looking for the last part?

Answer (score 1):

I (obviously) won't write you you the whole widget but I'm wailing to give you all you need:

First, you need PHP. I suggest you to learn PDO. It's very easy to use and pretty safe:

Example:

```
  <?php
     try {
       $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
       foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from FOO') as $row) {
          print_r($row);
       }
      $dbh = null;
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
       die();
      }
   ?>
```

[PDO documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Then, use HTML and CSS to style the thing.

Then, you use PHP to generate the HTML.

Then, you will use an javascript setInterval

Example for [setInterval](http://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/)

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Do something every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

If you need a different ID for each, the easiest way would be to do this:

```
   $counter = 0;
   foreach($foo as $bar){
     echo '<div id="slider'.$counter.'"></div>';
     //somecode
     $counter++;
   }
```

Tho, I do not recommand using this, you should just give one class to each of them and initiate them all at the same time in jQuery using the selector after

```
    $('.slider').myPlugin({
      //Plugins options
    })
```

Comment: this is not what I am looking

Comment: What are you looking for then? Somebody that writes the whole plugin for you?

Comment: you can recommend some website where plugin is available.

Comment: They have a slider included in the pack

Comment: I tried many slider. all slider having only single problem. this is the place I am confusing. I need here to pass some variable. load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider(); and <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">image here.</div>
    }); how to make the id ( slider as variable) both in html and jquery.

Comment: So you are using ajax if I am correct (jQuery function .load is that it?)

Comment: I am not using ajax. understand my question please. for example I need 10 slider per page if the records (row) are 10. so every slider need deferent ID. so I tried ID as variable. but it was not working. so if you can clear to make ID as variable. my problem will be solved.

Comment: Sorry there is not enough details in your question, post the code you did in your question and try to edit and comment it in a way we can understand it clearly, it will be better

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, it seems you're looking for this kind of solution.
Use of js `"jquery.bxslider.js"`, required css `"jquery.bxslider.css"`

```
//assuming this is your database retrieval
$slideImage[]   = "clody.jpg";
$slideImage[]   = "heaven.jpg";
$slideImage[]   = "park.jpg";
$slideImage[]   = "pool.jpg";
$slideImage[]   = "provence.jpg";

$slideStr       = "";
//utlize while loop if required
foreach($slideImage as $indKey=>$indSlideImg) {
    $slideStr .= '<div class="slide"><img src="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-5/data/tooltips/'.$indSlideImg.'" /></div>';
}
```

here in the above loop we created a sliding string, which we are going to utilize that into our slider.

```
<div class="bx-wrapper">
    <div class="bx-viewport">
        <div class="slider1">
            <?php echo $slideStr; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here comes the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider1').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 200,
    minSlides: 2,
    maxSlides: 3,
    slideMargin: 10
  });
});
```

hope it is helpful.

Comment: here you are calling ID as slider1. if i put 10 sliders. so what is the ID? i need ID in variable from html and jquery.

Comment: you could just give them all the class: slider, and then do it this way:

$('.slider')....

Do not initiate the slider for every instance your code will be horrible and long