# Multi slider in sigle page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Earlier I have asked question here: [how to make image slider into while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908217/how-to-make-image-slider-into-while-loop?noredirect=1#comment57556381_34908217) but could not find right answer.

Now I have some code modified. It is working fine.
still I need to simplify the javascript and css. can any one help me?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <!-- jQuery (required) -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


    <!-- Anything Slider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/anythingslider.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.anythingslider.js"></script>


    <!-- Define slider dimensions here -->
    <style>
    #slider1 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    #slider2 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    #slider3 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    #slider4 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    #slider5 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    #slider6 { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
    </style>

    <!-- AnythingSlider initialization -->
    <script>
        // DOM Ready
        $(function(){
            $('#slider1').anythingSlider();
        });

        $(function(){
            $('#slider2').anythingSlider();
        });

        $(function(){
            $('#slider3').anythingSlider();
        });

        $(function(){
            $('#slider4').anythingSlider();
        });

        $(function(){
            $('#slider5').anythingSlider();
        });

        $(function(){
            $('#slider6').anythingSlider();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body id="simple">





<?php 
for($x=1;$x<=6;$x++){
$Slider="slider".$x;
?>

    <div id="<?php echo $Slider;?>">
        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </div>
<?php }?>
    <!-- END AnythingSlider -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so you took someone else's code, and posted a new question, *rich*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using bunch of ids, combine them into one class `.slider`

```
<style>
    .slider { width: 200px; height: 250px; }
</style>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider').anythingSlider();
});
```

```
<?php 
for($x=1;$x<=6;$x++) {
?>

    <div class="slider">
        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

If you need to be able to access them separately, you can do this

```
<?php 
for($x=1;$x<=6;$x++) {
$Slider="slider".$x;
?>

    <div class="slider <?php echo $Slider;?>">
        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-1.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-civil-2.jpg" alt=""></li>

        <li><img src="demos/images/slide-env-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    </div>
<?php }?>
```

That way you will be able to control the CSS using just one class, but will still be able to access them separately by `$('.slider'+sliderNumber).doSomething()`

Comment: yes working fine.thanks lot.